# Replace DropdownIndicator with CSS triangle react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm new at React and JS as well and have one problem to solve. I need to replace DropdownIndicator with CSS triangle. Yes, I've found some similar issues (like that https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/4008) but my question is: is it possible to make it with CSS triangle into components.DropdownIndicator?
CSS tringle style I already have:

```
    width: '0',
    height: '0',
    borderLeft: '5px solid transparent',
    borderRight: '5px solid transparent',
    borderTop: '3px solid #929292'
```

components.DropdownIndicator I already have (it doesn't work cause this solution shows no indicator at all):

```
<Select
        ...            
    components={{ DropdownIndicator }}
       ...            
  />

const DropdownIndicator = props => {
    return (
        <components.DropdownIndicator {...props}>
            <span className={{
                width: '0',
                height: '0',
                borderLeft: '5px solid transparent',
                borderRight: '5px solid transparent',
                borderTop: '3px solid #929292'
            }}></span>
        </components.DropdownIndicator>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did my override

```
import React from 'react';
import { components } from 'react-select';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import Icon from '../../../../components/Icon.component';
import styles from '../Select.module.scss';

const DropdownIndicator = ({
  className,
  cx,
  getStyles,
  innerProps,
  selectProps,
  ...props
}) => (
  <components.DropdownIndicator
    {...props}
    className={classNames(styles['ul-select-indicator'], className)}
    cx={cx}
    getStyles={getStyles}
    innerProps={innerProps}
    selectProps={selectProps}
  >
    <Icon glyph="caret-down" />
  </components.DropdownIndicator>
);

export default DropdownIndicator;
```

I apply that with the `components` prop and it works like a charm.